# ant task "sshexec", how to print the remote message in the console?

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, console

I developed a plugin in eclipse, this plugin should call ant task `sshexec`. The problem is how can I print the remote messages in the eclipse console?

My code is like below:

```
 Project p = new Project(); 

 MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole("building", null); 
 IConsoleManager manager = (IConsoleManager) ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager(); 
 manager.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { console }); 
 manager.showConsoleView(console); 

 MessageConsoleStream cs = console.newMessageStream(); 
 cs.setColor(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE)); 
 PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(cs); 

 final DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger(); 
 consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(ps); 
 consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(ps); 
 consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO); 

 p.init(); 
 p.addBuildListener(consoleLogger); 
 ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper(); 
 helper.parse(p, buildFile); 

 p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

When executing the sshexec target to compile , I always get the output messages like

```
[sshexec] cd ...; ls ...; ....
```

It only prints the command I write, but the remote machine's compile message cannot print in the console. And once errors got in the compile procedure, it still returned build successfully.
How can I print the remote messages in the console and get the error result?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just solve this problem in another way.
I used the process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ant-launcher.jar -f build.xml") to execute the  ant task. But remember to start two threads to read the process.getInputStream() and process.getErrorStream().